# Turtlebot won't stop

Tags: ros, turtlebot, sudo, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
hyness@turtlebot:~$ sudo service turtlebot stop
[sudo] password for hyness: 
stop: Unknown instance:
```

why does my turtlebot do this? It will start just fine, but the stop command does not work. Please advise if you need screenshots, or any other additional info.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42676/turtlebot-won%27t-stop/) by [buma676](https://answers.ros.org/users/2990/buma676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is printed if the turtlebot service is not running when stop is called.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0